# Incorrect layout with dynamic cell height

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

[image]

I have a table view, and within that table view I have a cell that contains text and it can also contain an image if the user chooses to. However, I'm trying to make the cell smaller if the user chooses not to include an image. When I do this, its actually stretching my image to make the cell even larger. Does anyone know why this is happening? My code is:

```
    // get main queue to this block of code to communicate back
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        cell.textLbl.sizeToFit()

        // if no image on the cell
        if image.size.width == 0 && image.size.height == 0 {

            // move left textLabel if no picture
            cell.textLbl.frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width / 50 
            cell.textLbl.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.size.width - self.view.frame.size.width / 8 

            tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120
            tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
            cell.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()

        }
    }
```

Comment: what constraints do you have?

Comment: I'm just using the reset to suggested constrains that is provided in xcode